# Postgres functions, transactions and rollback

Tags: postgresql, transaction

I have a psql function that selects for update and then iterates through an array to update the table. If an error is found it correctly returns false, but does not rollback. So if the error is half way through the array, the first half will have been updated.

I was under the impression that all postgres functions were transactional. Is this not the case?

Should I look into converting my function to a stored procedure so I can get the benefits of transactions?

Thank you

Comment: The function participates in the transaction of the caller, so yes they are transactional. But you can't have a commit or rollback inside a function to begin with. The caller needs to do the rollback or the function needs to raise an error - then caller is _forced_ to do a rollback

Comment: Thank you very much a_horse_with_no_name :)